# access minikube service running on remote host

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have installed minikube on remote host. I have created a service like this:

> ```
> NAME        TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
> hello-svc   NodePort   10.108.103.37   <none>        8080:30985/TCP   2h
> ```

I have pods like this:

> ```
> kubectl get pods
> NAME           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
> hello-pod      1/1       Running   0          23h
> web-rs-7zjpx   1/1       Running   0          4h
> web-rs-dxrx5   1/1       Running   0          5h
> web-rs-jjw6x   1/1       Running   0          5h
> web-rs-p8cft   1/1       Running   0          5h
> web-rs-wt6vp   1/1       Running   0          5h
> ```

minikube service hello-svc --url

> http://192.168.39.160:30985

How I will be able to access the service at port 30985 from my local machine ? I tried using port forwarding from my localhost through ssh but it didn't worked.

> ssh -L 9000:192.168.XX.YY:30985 user@192.168.XX.YY

Comment: Does it work to execute this from your local machine? What's the response that you get? curl $(minikube service hello-minikube --url)

Comment: i tried  curl $(minikube service hello-minikube --url) on my remote m/c and I got an html page dump. can't execute above command from my local machine.

Comment: I have it working now. It needed forwarding on remote m/c. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

It needed port forwarding on remote m/c.